# Direction field of a first orden variable separable differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I solved the equation

$y'=y(1-y)$

and I found

$ln(y)-ln(1-y)=x+c$

i.e. $y=\frac{c_{1}e^{x}}{c_{2}e^{x}-1}$

However, as I try to plot the direction field (using isoclines) I get

$y-y^{2}-y'=0$

i.e. $y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y'}}{2}$

Does this means that the solutions must have a slope $y'<\frac{1}{4}$ at all points?

The thing is, when I plot the solution in my computer, it spits out some positive hiperbolae. Does this means that the solutions are only defined for values of $x$ to the left of the asymptote?

Note:

Wolframalpha gives me a solution $y=\frac{e^x}{c+e^x}$ wich seems a lot more elegant and easy to work with. Any idea on how to get this result?

Comment: Maybe try $z=y+1/2$. Also it is ich verlore. Plural would be verloren. For example we lose, wir verloren or they lose Sie verloren.

Comment: Hmm wait.  Did you take logarithms? How did you find that it should be x+c?

Comment: I solved it as a separable variable equation. $\frac{dy}{y-y^2}=dx$. Integrating both sides gives you the logarithms and the constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the wolfram solution, here are some steps

$$y'=y(1-y)$$
$$\int \frac {dy}{y(1-y)}=x+K$$
$$\int \frac {dy}{y}+ \int \frac{dy}{1-y}=x+K$$
$$\ln (y)-\ln {(y-1)}=x+K$$
$$\ln (\frac y{y-1})=x+K$$
$$\frac y{y-1}=Ce^x$$
$$ y=-\frac {Ce^x }{1-Ce^x}
\implies y=\frac {Ke^x }{1+Ke^x}$$
$$ y=\frac {e^x }{R+e^x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the derivative of the equation $y'=y(1-y)$ and make it equal to $0$ gives us:

$y''=y'(1-2y)$

$y'(1-2y)=0$

$\Rightarrow y'(1-2y)=0$

$\Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{2}$

Using this on the original equation gives us $y'=1/4$

$\frac{1}{4} $ is a maximum for the slope!

The slope is indeed always less than $\frac{1}{4}$. In fact, if we study the direction field outside the region $0<y<1$, the slope will be always negative.